# Making a Method common for different versions of same class

Tags: java

I am generating Classes from XSD. For each revision in XSD, A new class is generated with same name but under a different package. If "Foo"is the class, the class name will be : ***model.v1.Foo***, ***model.v2.Foo*** etc. fro each revision.

Irrespective of the version of class, some operations are common. Is there any way to create a common method, that can take up any version of **Foo** class

```
public static String doOperation(Foo foo){
    //Do some operation
}
```

The *DoOperation* method needs to be common for all the versions.

Comment: you are adding version into package name? why?

Comment: That's the way it already exists and I won't be able to change that. All the versions are still in use and it has to be supported.

Comment: can all `Foo` versions implement an interface ? Or be subclass (extend )  a class ?

Comment: @c0der No, these classes are generated already and provided to us.

Comment: Do all `Foo` versions have a common super class ? Can you extend `Foo` and use its subclass ?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is create an interface like:

```
public interface FooIF {

    public default String doOperation(Foo foo){

        System.out.println("doOperation executed");

        return null;
    }
}
```

And have `Foo` implement it:

```
public class Foo implements FooIF{

    public Foo() {

    }

    public static void main( String[] args) {

        Foo f = new Foo();
        f.doOperation(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: They are auto generated classes from XSD using maven plugins, I wont be able to modify them.